# Need to copy 100 TB of data from Dell EQL NAS to another Dell NAS, what is the best and fastest method?

Tags: network-attached-storage, copy, dell-equallogic

I have a Dell Equallogic NAS group, capacity 500 TB.  Need to move off 100 TB out of it to another similar NAS group.  Storage arrays are PS6500E (5 of them in one group) and NAS heads are FS7500.  The second group has same setup and sits right next to the first group.  What would be the fastest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

With Equallogic, it's probably the fastest way to use the built in group move tool for a volume.

See [here](http://psonlinehelp.equallogic.com/en/v6.0/Content/tlskr/task/Moving_a_volume_to_a_pool.htm#Pools_3641632907_1149419) for details.

> To move a volume to a new pool:
>
> 1. Click Volumes.
> 2. Expand Volumes and select the volume name.
> 3. Click Move volume to open the Move volume dialog.
> 4. If you are changing the pool assignment for a synchronous replication volume, you must specify the SyncActive or SyncAlternate
>      volume.
> 5. Select the destination pool for the volume.
> 6. Click OK.
>
> The volume status is shown as moving until the pool move operation
>   completes.

Comment: This would be applicable for migrating a volume from one pool to another in the same Equallogic group, but the question is actually referring to migrating data between 2 different groups. The migration is also happening with a sub-set of data contained by a volume, which requires a file-system level data migration. FYI

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend that you get in touch with Dell support with this question. Though you're looking for the "fastest" way to achieve this, it would be best to have their guidance in ensuring that it's done the "right" way too.

The fastest way to migrate the data is by copying with multi-threaded I/O, which takes advantage of the distributed nature of the file system utilized by the FS NAS systems. The best way to accomplish this actually depends on your firmware version, configuration, and other environmental factors.

Give support a call - they'll gladly help guide you through the process!